# Camel MongoDB empty body problem, how to configure FullDocument.UPDATE_LOOKUP

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-camel

I am trying to use ChangeStreams in MongoDB 4.4 and Camel 3.12.0. According to the [Camel documents](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.12.x/mongodb-component.html), the Exchange body will contain the full document of any change. I am building my route as below:

```
   from("mongodb:mongoClient?consumerType=changeStreams&database=test&collection=accounts")
    .process(new MongoIdProcessor())
    .to("solrCloud://minikube:8983/solr?zkHost=minikube:2181,minikube:2182,minikube:2183&collection=accounts&autoCommit=true")
```

What I noticed is that if I issue an update (updateOne, updateMany) command on the "accounts" collection, there isn't any data in the Exchange object during processing.

```
    Message message = exchange.getMessage(); // Null
    Message in = exchange.getIn(); 
    ObjectId objectId = in.getHeader("_id", ObjectId.class); // Present
```

Digging a little deeper, it seems that in MongoDbChangeStreamsThread.java, the collection being watched does not have the options set correctly.

```
@Override
protected MongoCursor initializeCursor() {
    ChangeStreamIterable<Document> iterable = bsonFilter != null
            ? dbCol.watch(bsonFilter)
            : dbCol.watch();
```

It should be this instead

```
@Override
protected MongoCursor initializeCursor() {
    ChangeStreamIterable<Document> iterable = bsonFilter != null
            ? dbCol.watch(bsonFilter).fullDocument(FullDocument.UPDATE_LOOKUP)
            : dbCol.watch().fullDocument(FullDocument.UPDATE_LOOKUP);
```

Do I really have to make the change in this class, or is there some configuration somewhere I can set? I'm concerned about maintaining code for this modified class of the Camel library.